# WebAR project in playcanvas

Tags: javascript, web-ar, playcanvas

I want to access webcam in my playcanvas project.And also want to use the face detection API for my project.Now how should I write code for this? Can anyone help me to make a project in playcanvas? Is there any professional who works with webAR in playcanvas?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)